# How to convert a number of months, into months and years?

Tags: javascript

If I have X months, using Javascript, how could I convert that number into `X years and X months`?

Comment: `var x = 14, months = x % 12, years = (x - months) / 12;` - I'll let you do the string work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a function for it with stress on singular and plural words.

```js
function getWords(monthCount) {
    function getPlural(number, word) {
        return number === 1 && word.one || word.other;
    }

    var months = { one: 'month', other: 'months' },
        years = { one: 'year', other: 'years' },
        m = monthCount % 12,
        y = Math.floor(monthCount / 12),
        result = [];

    y && result.push(y + ' ' + getPlural(y, years));
    m && result.push(m + ' ' + getPlural(m, months));
    return result.join(' and ');
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    console.log(getWords(i));
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For some number `x` and some divisor `y` compute the division `(div)` and remainder `(rem)` as:

```
var div = Math.floor(x/y);
var rem = x % y;
```

So, in your example:

```
var years = Math.floor(months/12);
var months = months % 12;
```

Comment: Clean, simple and does the job perfect. 
Thanks m8. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
months = 14

console.log(
  (months / 12 | 0) + " years and " + months % 12 +" months"
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function

```
function months2years(months) {
var dur1 = Math.floor(months/12)
var dur2 = (months/12)-dur1
var dur3 = Math.floor(dur2*12)
return dur1+" years and "+dur3+" months"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get years and months you only need to use this function:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function years_months(month) 
    {
        if(month==12) {
            var y1 = 1 + " Year";
            return y1;
        } else {
            var y=(month/12);
            var mm=(month%12);
            var ym = y + "Years"+" " + mm + "Months";
            return ym;
        }
    }
</script>
```

you may improve this according to your need. This is only an idea, how you can get your solution.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function, It's tested with Jest (unit test).

```
function durationFormatter(monthsCount) {
  const years = Math.floor(monthsCount / 12);
  let yearsDur = years > 0 ? `${years} year` : '';
  yearsDur = years > 1 ? `${yearsDur}s` : yearsDur;

  const restMonths = monthsCount - years * 12;
  let monthsDur = restMonths > 0 ? `${restMonths} month` : '';
  monthsDur = restMonths > 1 ? `${monthsDur}s` : monthsDur;

  const and = years > 0 && restMonths > 0 ? ', and ' : '';

  return `${yearsDur}${and}${monthsDur}`;
}
```

Test suite

```
describe('Duration formatter', () => {
  test('formate 12 months duration to 1 year', () => {
    const formatedDuration = durationFormatter(12);
    const expected = '1 year';
    expect(formatedDuration).toBe(expected);
  });

  test('formate 24 months duration to 2 years', () => {
    const formatedDuration = durationFormatter(24);
    const expected = '2 years';
    expect(formatedDuration).toBe(expected);
  });

  test('formate 6 months duration to 6 months', () => {
    const formatedDuration = durationFormatter(6);
    const expected = '6 months';
    expect(formatedDuration).toBe(expected);
  });

  test('formate 1 month duration to 1 month', () => {
    const formatedDuration = durationFormatter(1);
    const expected = '1 month';
    expect(formatedDuration).toBe(expected);
  });

  test('formate 13 months duration to 1 year and 1 month', () => {
    const formatedDuration = durationFormatter(13);
    const expected = '1 year, and 1 month';
    expect(formatedDuration).toBe(expected);
  });

  test('formate 14 months duration to 1 year and 2 months', () => {
    const formatedDuration = durationFormatter(14);
    const expected = '1 year, and 2 months';
    expect(formatedDuration).toBe(expected);
  });

  test('formate 25 months duration to 2 years and 1 month', () => {
    const formatedDuration = durationFormatter(25);
    const expected = '2 years, and 1 month';
    expect(formatedDuration).toBe(expected);
  });

  test('formate 26 months duration to 2 years and 2 months', () => {
    const formatedDuration = durationFormatter(26);
    const expected = '2 years, and 2 months';
    expect(formatedDuration).toBe(expected);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dur1 = Math.floor(months/12);
var dur3 = months - (dur1*12);
```